# how to auto sign out user after using "sign in with slack" with oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, slack

after using oauth2 flow for slack ("Sign in with Slack") and making appropriate API calls, we need to make sure users are properly signed out of Slack as well, else, on a shared computer, subsequent users would gain access to their info.

we're using oauth2 with slack and all is well but we don't know how to explicitly log users out of slack. We spied a generic url (`https://slack.com/signout/{first-part-of-oauth2-client-id-here}`) which does take the user to their main page, with a dialog and a button. But in our case we've already asked the user if they want us to log them out of slack so that dialog is jarring (and redundant).

We can't find an api to allow for this use case.

This is NOT asking for access_token revocation (which we do as well), this is simply signing the user out of that particular computer (after they asked to sign out of our app)

Comment: I don't think that is possible, since it utilizes the current Slack session / account and is linked to the current browser (you can be logged into multiple workspaces at the same time, and you can use different Slack accounts with different browsers on the same computer at the same time). To be sure I would suggest to ask the Slack team directly (and please post the answer here if you do).